# GetDirectories from network in c#

Tags: c#, networking, directory

I am trying to create a listing of folders on the system (actually I am trying to make a custom "explorer").

I need to be able to list network drives, but I don't know how.

The only thing I know how to do is:

```
string[] localDrives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
```

If I even try

```
string[] initDrives = Directory.GetDirectories(initialDirectory);
```

where `initialDirectory` is anything, from

```
initialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

to a network drive (I thought I can, in a worst case scenario, hard-code a path with `\\`), 
the `string[]` remains `null`.

How can I get a list of all the paths available, or the directories and subdirectories given a path that could be on the network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This codeproject article may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20547/How-to-Browse-Network-Folders-using-Folder-Dialog

Comment: This is a very interesting project, even though I used the Directory.GetDirectories(initialDirectory) after all, and hard-coded an ".." button... It looks ugly, but the version they have is extremely slow, and doesn't resolve all the network paths, I don't know why. Still it is nice to learn.